# Get list of connected IP addresses PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing an app which requires the IP address people who are on my website.
So, I've seen that people use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` Or

```
function GetIP()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER)) { if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) 
    { 
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; 
    } 
        elseif(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) 
    { 
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
    } 
} 
    else 
    {
        if ( getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ) ) 
            { 
                $ip = getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ); 
            } 

        elseif ( getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ) ) 
            {
                $ip = getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ); 
            } 

        else 
            { 
                $ip = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );  
            } 
} 
return $ip; 
}
```

For more correct IP addresses. If the IP address isn't correct in my app, it shouldn't be a problem.
But I need a list of the IP addresses who are connected to the server.
My question is, how is this possible? 
How can I go get all the IP addresses connected to the server? 
Because if I use the code, it only shows one address.
I've tried using loops in my code but it unfortunately didn't work.
Any suggestions? Thoughts? I'd appreciate it!

Kind regards,

Sjors

Comment: That code will only work for the individual devices connecting to the server. So what you'd have to do is write it to some form of storage on the server, a file or DB - you'd then see all of the IPs connecting. Alternatively, you should have access to log files that already do that.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Alright, I'll try that! Thank you very much!

Comment: Also be aware that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` (and any other headers) can be spoofed very easily. Only `REMOTE_ADDR` can be relied upon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only a very small number of *active connections* at any one time. The browser connects to your server, requests a website, gets the response, **and then disconnects**. It is only actually connected to your server momentarily. How long the user will leave the page open in their browser is an entirely different matter.

If you want something like this, you need to define what you mean by "connected." Probably something like "IP addresses which have requested a page within the last *x* minutes." You'll simply have to save the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` of visitors in a database with a timestamp, and get the latest *x* IPs from that database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Save session data to a database table. And get all the IP addresses for active sessions.

You can do this on the core container, so in every request to your application the list is updated, and you can use the data on all containers of your application.